# How to parse and deserialize an XML string with many elements if you do not have a corresponding Java object?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I got an XML string with many elements and I wonder is there a way to parse it into some kind of Java bean (Properties?) if I do not have a java bean defined? Mapping all the elements to java bean properties manually can be time-consuming, so I am looking for some kind of 'optimization' here .
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If it's one level deep you can use jackson XmlMapper and map it to a Map'<'String,String>

post an example of the XML if you want more help.